# The sum of prime number is incorrect

Tags: python, sum, primes

The code is not returning the sum of of the prime numbers, what I'm i doing wrong?

```
the_sum = 0
for number in range(20):
    if number > 3:
        for i in range(2,number):
            if (number%i)==0:
                break
        else:
            the_sum += number
            print (the_sum)
```

Comment: Print out the prime numbers and see if they are correct!

Comment: Probably you want to set `the_sum = 5`, iterate over `range(4, 20)` and remove condition. Or just iterate over `range(2, 20)`

Comment: *2* and *3* are prime, too. You're not using a function, only functions can *return*. Btw:  Nice use of a for loop with an else clause.

Comment: Check numbers between 2 to square root of the number. You don't need to go to the number itself....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 is a prime number, you need to include that. also 3, you are checking > 3 , it should be >=

```py
the_sum = 0
for number in range(2,20):
    for i in range(2,number):
        if (number%i)==0:
            break
    else:
        the_sum += number
print(the_sum)
```

Comment: @OlvinRoght if you do `range(2, 20)` the sum will always be 0 since it will always evaluate `number % number`

Comment: @BTables, are you sure?

Comment: Thanks, I had to exit the loop at EOL. It works perfectly now.

Comment: @OlvinRoght If you were talking about the inner loop, yes I am. Looping over `range(2,20)` does guarantee you'll land on each number [2,20)

Comment: @saleemdamry why have you moved to the below answer after accepting this one ? any specific reason?

Answer (score 1):

```
the_sum = 0
for number in range(20):
    if number >= 3:
        for i in range(2,number):
            if (number%i)==0:
                break
            elif i == (number-1):
                the_sum += number
    elif number==2:
        the_sum += number

print (the_sum)
```

please Try this.

Comment: And what it will change?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following lines of the code the if conditon I changed it to `if number >= 2` instead of `if number > 3` since two is a prime as well, it would need to be added in the sum as well.

**Note**: That the range function always starts generating iterables with a `0` not a `1` and ends with one less than the limit so for example:

> range(0, 4)

would generate numbers from `0 to 4`

```
the_sum = 0
for number in range(1, 4):
    # numbers = [1, 2, 3,]
    if number >= 2:
        for i in range(2,number):

            if (number%i)==0:
                break
        else:
            the_sum += number


print (the_sum)
```

Comment: Could somebody explain why you iterate over some range and put condition inside loop to cut half of this range? Why no to initialize required range?